# Could I use a string variable as a jQuery input mask argument?

Tags: jquery, input, mask

I am trying to use a variable as a mask input argument, and I haven't had any success.

```
Dim sgra_id As String // SGRA_ID.VALUE WILL BE RETRIEVED FROM A COOKIE

$('#" + tbx.ClientID + "').mask(sgra_id, { placeholder: ' ' });
```

Can anyone please tell me how it works?

Comment: sgra_id will be "9999/99/99SCHOOL_NAME" 
THE SCHOOL_NAME WILL BE GET FROM COOKIE ..
SO I NEED USE A VARIABLE TO BE THE MASK'S ARGUMENT.
PLEASE HELP ME .

Comment: dim sgra_id as string this is not the correct declaration of jquery you have to use var sgra_id ="";

Comment: thx.you are right,and i knew the "dim ... " is not the correct ,
in fact ,the code i wrote down is not what i really use in my prog. .
so,that is not the point of my question.
the point is how could i use a variable as the parameter of mask() .
thX

Answer (score 0):

may be this one can help you

```
$('#date').mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"-"});
```

[how-to-mask-input-with-jquery](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery/)

Comment: THX.BUT THAT IS NOT WHAT I NEED.